# How to avoid negative roots with a Newton's method?

Tags: computational-physics

I'm currently trying to solve a system of (3) nonlinear equations of (3) variables which are the baryonic density, the isospin asymmetry and and the density of a fluid with the Broyden's method (a quasi-Newton method) included in the GSL.

The problem is that I don't know how to avoid negative roots. I don't want them because it's obviously nonphysical. I guess I should use some conditions but I don't know which ones... I'm programming in C.

Could you help please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software design and not physics. [scicomp.se] or [so] might be better suited.

Comment: That said, check out Boost's root finders, pretty sure they're all bounded/bracketed solvers (it also wouldn't surprise me that they reduce to bisection under that, but who knows).

Comment: There are also other as-efficient root solvers available that surely can be bracketed easily ([Brent's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method) & [Ridders' method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridders%27_method) both come to mind).

Comment: Kinsol, part of the Sundials solver suite (http://computation.llnl.gov/projects/sundials/kinsol), solves systems of nonlinear algebraic equations, allows you to specify inequality constraints on the variables, and is callable from C.

Comment: If it's not too difficult, perhaps you could try a change of variables.  For example, instead of solving for T, you could solve for ln(T).

Comment: @nukeguy I'm not sure a Log change of variable is well advised here, as it might lead to poor conditioning. A linear COV might make more sense, though the solution of Bill seems most direct.

Comment: @SpencerBryngelson Perhaps, yes, it depends very much on his problem of interest.  But I feel that, if the equations represent something physical and his solution must be positive for a good physical, then changing the variables to something that prevents it from becoming negative should be okay.  I wonder what the Jacobian of his nonlinear system near 0 looks like without a change of variables.

Comment: Maybe you should include the system of equations you're solving, for reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.

I still use the GSL but I changed the Broyden's method for the classical discrete Newton's method because I saw that Broyden's method "is not recommended for serious use" (source: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Algorithms-without-Derivatives.html#Algorithms-without-Derivatives).

I also programmed "mirrors" to avoid nonphysical values.

Thanks for the assistance.